# What hapened with without Exception Handling in laravel 6+?

Tags: laravel

I had create 3 laravel projetcs for versions 5.8, 6.* and 7.*.
`$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` doesn't work, i got "Call to undefined method". It only works on the v5.8 installation. It have been removed from newers versions of laravel?

ty

Comment: Can you provide specific code snippet